# How do I make a regex that only matches integers?

Tags: python, regex

I have this polynomial in a string.

```
x^3+0.125x+2
```

I want to match here the 3 and the 2, but not the 0.125. Just the integers. Be best I came with so far is this, but this still matches the 25 in 0.125.

```
(?<!\.)\d+(?!\.)
```

Comment: "best I came with so far is this"? Is *what*? And in which language are you programming?

Comment: Sorry I didn't put the regex in a code block. I didn't render correctly. I'm programming in python.

Comment: copied the wrong regex. This is the correct one. It might be time to go to sleep.

Comment: Don't know why this was -1. There is nothing wrong with this question, and if anything, I think it's a good enough question to be +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'(?<!\.)\b\d+\b(?!\.)', "x^3+0.125x+2")
['3', '2']
```

use `\b\d+\b` to make sure that matching entire number

Comment: Thanks. It does exactly what I needed. I didn't think of using the \b.

Comment: It didn't match integers net to an 'x' or other letters. I changed it to "(?<!\.)(\b|(?<=\D))\d+(\b|(?=\D))(?!\.)" and it now works like a charm. Thanks for you help.

Comment: It does not accept the minus sign in front of numbers, but its not it's necessary to me. My plan is to use it to transform the integers into floats, by adding a dot behind them. I might make one that accepts the minus sign later.

Comment: `\b` is too blunt an instrument for this task.  Here's how I would write it: `r'(?<![\d.])\d+(?![\d.])'` - But I hope you're not trying to parse the whole polynomial with regexes, because it can't be done.

Comment: I'm reading every term individually by reading the power of x, then remove the x^## and eval() the resulting string. I used to use float(), but this didn't allow me to enter fractions. So that's why I changed it to eval(). I decided to do this since I kept forgetting adding the dot every time to make it a float.

Answer (score 1):

An integer is a number that contains only digits, an optional `e` or `E` (only if followed by numbers) and optionally starts with a `-`. To the left there can only be a non-number and non-letter (since `x2` would be considered a variable name) or nothing. To the right there can only be a non-number or nothing (`2x` on the right would be `2*x`).

The following pattern should match all integers in a string according to the given specification:

```
r'(?:^|(?<=[^\d\w\.]))(?:(?:(?<![\d\w])|^)\-)?\d+(?:[eE]\d+)?(?!\.)(?=[^\d]|$)''
```

Comment: That's a good one. The one in the previous answer satisfies my requirements, but this one is impressive. I will have to give it a more detailed look.